# Reducing the space between the `xlab` and with the x-axis in a forest plot (metafor package) in R

Tags: r, plot, metafor

I'm trying to reduce the space between the `xlab` (titled: `"Log Risk Ratio"`) and the x-axis (*see picture below*) in the forest plot generated by the `metafor` package in R with no success.

Is there any way to achive this?

```
library(metafor)

dat <- escalc(measure="RR", ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, data=dat.bcg)

forest(dat$yi, dat$vi, mgp = c(2, .3, 0)) # Tried setting `mgp` without success!
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

forest calls base R plot function, so you set the xlab to be "" first, and use mtext to manually add the text. Increasing padj will move your label away from the axis.

```
forest(dat$yi, dat$vi, mgp = c(2, .3, 0),xlab="") 
mtext(side=1,"Log Risk Ratio",padj=2)
```

[image]